# Hashcat Turkish character problem

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, research

I'm using cudahashcat, it haven't special chars like "öçşĞÜ" in standart charsets. I defined charsets with windows-1254 and other encoding types(and -1 öÖçÇğĞşŞüÜıİ?a parameter), i tried but they didn't worked. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Hashcat is a tool for hash cracking, so where can i ask this question which about a security tool?